# What is wrong with my JDK installation?

Tags: opensuse, path, java

I tried to compile a Hello world example in java and got a gcc error. As far as I understand it, gcc is trying to compile my java class (and for some reason failing to find the main method, but that's beside the point).

I have openSUSE 12.1 64 bit and JDK 1.7 (installed from Oracle's rpm). I have `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/` in my $PATH. When I try to compile a java file, I get:

```
rumtscho@bradbury:/tmp> javac Hello.java
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.6/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: 
In function `_start':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.14.1/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64
/elf/start.S:109: undefined reference to `main'
```

Why is this happening and how can I correct the problem?

My complete $PATH is:

```
rumtscho@bradbury:/tmp> echo $PATH
/home/rumtscho/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:.:/home/rumtscho/bin:/home/rumtscho/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/home/rumtscho/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/rumtscho/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/:/home/rumtscho/bin:/home/rumtscho/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/home/rumtscho/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/rumtscho/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/
```

Comment: I don't understand your question: is your problem that gcc is invoked in preference to some other java compiler? Or that gcc doesn't work? Does `Hello.java` have a `main` method? What is the exact value of your `$PATH`? Presumably the gcc `javac` is before the Oracle `javac`, or maybe `javac` is a configurable symlink (some distributions do this — I don't know about SuSE).

Comment: @Gilles Yes, I want the oracle compiler to be used when I call javac. For some reason, my $PATH seems doubled, I don't know if this is related. The application consists of nothing but a main method (which prints "Hello world"), so it is also a bit strange that gcc doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands are looked up in `$PATH` in the order in which the directories are listed. In your case, it is likely from your description that there is no `/home/rumtscho/bin/javac`, no `/usr/local/bin/javac`, but a `/usr/bin/javac` that is the GCC Java compiler (or a symbolic link to it).

SuSE has an “alternatives” mechanism to handle programs that have multiple implementations. According to the [SuSE documentation on installing Java](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aInstalling_Java), SuSE's Java packages use this mechanism. If the Oracle package respects this interface, then run

```
update-alternatives --config javac
```

to select your favorite Java compiler (you should do the same with `java` to select a matching runtime environment).

If the Oracle binary is not mentioned in the list, you can manually switch to it:

```
ln -snf /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/{java,javac} /etc/alternatives/
```

Alternatively (but this is not recommended if the alternatives method works), you can create a symbolic link to your prefered `javac` in your `~/bin` directory (per-user setting) or in `/usr/local/bin` (system-wide setting).

```
ln -s ../../java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/javac /usr/local/bin
```

Another way would be to reorder your `PATH` to have the Oracle JDK directory first. In your `~/.profile`, make sure to add `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin` at the beginning of your `PATH`. You can take the opportunity to remove it if it was already in the `$PATH`, to avoid duplicate entries (which are harmless except for a very slight slowdown when looking for a command at the end of `$PATH` or looking up a non-existent command name).

```
prepend_to_path () {
  PATH=":$PATH:"
  case "$PATH" in
    *":$1:"*) PATH="${PATH%%":$1:"*}:${PATH#*":$1:"}";;
  esac
  PATH="$1${PATH%:}"
}
prepend_to_path /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin
```

Comment: I just found the symlink under alternatives and changed it, and everything worked. I was busy writing this in an answer of my own when you posted your, much more complete answer. Thanks!

Comment: Although `alternatives` did not work for me (it came up with only one), it gave me the right direction. Fixing the symlink manually did the trick.